# storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: " ") as! viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have as a Menu tableview in my custom navigation bar. If i click on one cell , it should take me to another view controller. But my app crashes when i click on it.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return menu_items.count  //It has 5 values
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = menu_items[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = .white

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


    let item = menu_items[indexPath.row]

    if (item == "Patienten") {


         tableView.removeFromSuperview()

        let vc =  self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "patientView") as! patientViewVC //App crashes here
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

    } else if (item == "Mitarbeiter") {


    } else if (item == "Kalender") {


    } else if (item == "Tourenplanung") {


       tableView.removeFromSuperview()

        let vc =  storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tour") as! tourVC //App crashes here
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)


    }else if (item == "Abmelden") {

        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginvc") as! LoginVC  //App crashes here
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = colorLightGreen

}
```

}

**I have many times verified all Identifier names and view controller names are correct.**

Comment: It crashes? What's the error message in the console? Are the `UIViewController` on the same storyboard as the current one?

Comment: are you sure you have  `patientViewVC` in same storyboard where tableview is ?

Comment: @Larme i don't see any error message in console , I see EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION on that line .

Comment: @JonSnow yes, I have only one storyboard. And all view controllers are in same

Comment: could show us more the error message in console? there should be something.

Comment: @MuhammadFauziMasykur I get only `(lldb)` nothing else

Comment: Is the custom class set in storyboard Identity inspector to proper type for each scene?

Comment: check `self.storyboard` are you getting nil or not

Comment: @JonSnow yes I do get nil . Why is it so?

Comment: Probably the class you are calling it from is not instantiated from storyboard.

Comment: I'm not an expert in Swift, but `let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginvc") as! LoginVC` That line is calling for a crash if `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginvc")` returns nil, or if it's not of the correct class, correct? Then, could you decompose these lines with an if let and check each case?

Comment: I am not aware about the actual reason may be @jonaszmclaren  is right  .Only one solution left is create Storyboard with name -> initiate with identifier and present it

Comment: @jonaszmclaren , its not true . all the classes are instantiated from storyboard.

Comment: If the class you are calling this code from is instantiated from storyboard, then `storyboard` cannot be nil.

Comment: A solution would be to manually instantiate UIStoryboard instance and it should work, but you should think why is `storyboard` nil.

Comment: Is there any other way to reach viewcontrollers mother than `self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "")` ?

Comment: @swiftuser123 From where you are showing This view controller (TableView not patientViewVC) check there `self.storybaord`

Comment: `let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)`

Comment: `self.storyboad` gets current storyboard, provided that current view controller is instantiated from storyboard. The code from @JonSnow is another way of getting a storyboard instance, but as I said, something is not right here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you load a correct storyboard before instantiating the viewController.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let item = menu_items[indexPath.row]

    if (item == "Patienten") {
        tableView.removeFromSuperview()

        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
        let vc =  storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "patientView") as! patientViewVC
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)

    } else if (item == "Mitarbeiter") {


    } else if (item == "Kalender") {


    } else if (item == "Tourenplanung") {


        tableView.removeFromSuperview()
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
        let vc =  storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tour") as! tourVC //App crashes here
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)


    }else if (item == "Abmelden") {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginvc") as! LoginVC  //App crashes here
        self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }


    let selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = colorLightGreen

}
```

StoryboardName above is the name of the storyboard that contains the patientViewVC, tourVC, LoginVC

Comment: Wow, You saved me!  `let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "StoryboardName", bundle: nil)`  works like charm!

Comment: @swiftuser123 : Always welcome buddy :) Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

A view controller in storyboard needs to have a custom class set in Identity inspector:

[image]

Then you can cast it to desired type. If all the view controllers are in the same storyboard, you can instantiate them with `storyboard` property of self. If they are in different storyboard, you have to instantiate UIStoryboard instance with corresponding name and use it.

Btw, why are you calling `tableView.removeFromSuperview()` after cell selection?